# Error with WordPress Plugin after updating to PHP 7.4

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

Hey guys I would extremely appreciate it if someone can help me out with an issue I am having on my WordPress website after updating to PHP 7.4 (I am not that tech-savvy).

I thought it would be a good idea to update to PHP 7.4 from 7.1 for security reasons, before the update I ensured that all of my plug-ins were updated and my WordPress was running the latest version.

After the update everything was smooth except for one small section on my home screen.

[image: Website on version PHP 7.4]

I believe I know the plugin used for this section, it is WPBakery and I do not have the license for it so it is running on version 6.1

I also have the code stating where the problem is: (line 817)

```
//Process Box
add_shortcode('process', 'process_func');
function process_func($atts, $content = null){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'shadow'     =>  '',    
        'number'     =>  '',    
        'title'      =>  '',     
        'image'      =>  '',   
        'style'      =>  'style1',   
    ), $atts));
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image,'full');
    $img = $img[0];
    ob_start(); 
?>
```

I believe line 817 is the $img = $img[0];

This is what the section of the website looks like in PHP Version 7.2

[image: Website on version PHP 7.2]

If someone understands the issue here and can explain it I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: If you need more context please let me know what you need me to provide you

Comment: You are right. Can you var_dump the content of $img? What happens that you try to access something that or works differently then expected (which somehow the older php version accepted) or that it does not exists where 7.4 throws a notice. I expect the last though but the only way to know for sure is to dump it first

Comment: Hello Dirkos, thank you for getting back to me with this question.                                                                          Where exactly should I perform a var_dump? I have access to all of the content for this website but I am not sure where I should do a var_dump, do I add "var_dump" right above that line of code?                                                                                             I apologize for not understanding how to do this.

Comment: Also the error code that is stated on Wordpress is "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value type bool in /homepages/22/d466722045/htdocs/clickandbuilds/newww/wp-content/plugins/ot_composer/functions/shortcodes.ph[/ on line 817

Comment: Just in case you did not see the images

Comment: Yes, please run a var_dump($img); above that 817 line to ensure we see all the debug info.

Comment: Hi Dirkos, I have been attempting to run a var_dump the past few days and I did not want to bother you but I still have no idea how or where to run a var_dump. I have tried plcaing var_dump over the code in notepad, wpcontent through data hoster, and winscp but I have no idea how to actually "run" the var_dump and to get the values.

Comment: Whenever I look online there is no mention of what software people use to run this code so I am hoping you could instruct me of how to run it.

Comment: I only see your response just now. Is this still relevant or did you figure it out?